# Google play downloads app and then tells me cannot load as no devices

Tags: google-play-store

I have an android tablet and finally got it to connect and stay connected to wifi however the google play store will take its time and download to tablet but it never shows in my download file and after all the time downloading then google displays the you have "no devices" message. How can I get my downloaded apps to show anywhere on my tablet please?

Comment: More information is needed.  Which tablet do you have?  Did the tablet come with the Play Store app pre-installed, or are you trying to download the app to your tablet via the web [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Menu>
Settings>Apps>All>
Google Framework Services>Clear Data

Again do the same thing with the Play Store App.

Reboot your Tablet and check it.

See if you can click the install button on PC and if the apps are pushed onto the tablet.